# CORS missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'

Tags: asp.net, cors, azure-logic-apps, openapi, built.io

I have configured an OpenApi endpoint, but some services fail to connect.

For example Built.io Flows can read the OpenAPI spec (JSON), but crashes when I select an operation, and Azure logic apps tells me there is a potential CORS issue when importing the OpenApi spec.

Other services work correctly though, like:

- https://editor.swagger.io/
- https://apidevtools.org/swagger-parser/online/index.html

They correctly fetch the OpenApi doc (v3.0.1) and mark it as valid.

To debug the issue I have temporary allowed all methods, origins and headers.

This is the example output of a pre-flight request:

```
curl --request OPTIONS
  --url https://my-endpoint
  --header 'accept: application/json'
  --header 'access-control-request-headers: X-Test'
  --header 'access-control-request-method: GET'
  --header 'origin: https://flow.built.io'
  --head
```

And response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store
Server:
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Test
Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcYWFtXFNDSFxzdHlsZWxhYnMubVxzcmNcU3R5bGVsYWJzLk0uUG9ydGFsLldlYi5VSVx2MVxvcGVuYXBpXERlbW9Eb21haW4=?=
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2019 11:21:01 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The actual request:

```
  curl --request GET 
  --url https://my-endpoint
  --header 'accept: application/json'
  --header 'origin: https://flow.built.io'
  --head
```

And response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 775
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: "Lk4Y9t0X5UEvgxtRUQ0MGoqYu4l4cN53Ji5NpB3lhzI="
Server:
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcYWFtXFNDSFxzdHlsZWxhYnMubVxzcmNcU3R5bGVsYWJzLk0uUG9ydGFsLldlYi5VSVx2MVxvcGVuYXBpXERlbW9Eb21haW4=?=
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2019 11:26:00 GMT
```

The CORS headers look correct to me, but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' is missing? Can this be the issue?

I'm using ASP.NET Framework with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors' 5.2.7, configured as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

On my controller I have this attribute:

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "*", PreflightMaxAge = 60)]
```

Comment: What’s the exact error message the browser is logging in the devtools console? What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response? Is the failure occurring for the OPTIONS response or is it instead occurring for the GET response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker They are both 200 in Azure Logic Apps. For Built.io I can't see this, because the first call https://flow.built.io/enterprise/v1/activities/fetchswaggerspec and then `https://flow.built.io/enterprise/v1/activities/swagger/.../get_details?api=...` which hide the real request. Both are 200 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue... Built.io and Azure logic apps do not support Swagger/OpenApi version 3. The problem was not CORS, even though it was stated so by Azure logic apps.